# How to Create Custom Image Asset in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-drawable

I am sorry if my question is too bad, I am new in android programmer.
Is it possible to create custom Image Asset in Android Studio?

For example: I want to create image asset in drawable directory with size image:

```
- drawable-mdpi: 100x100
- drawable-hdpi: 200x200
- drawable-xhdpi: 300x300
- drawable-xxhdpi: 400x400
- drawable-xxxhdpi: 500x500
```

If I create new image asset with Asset Type: Launcher Icon it is too small.
Any help will appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Check this http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html

Comment: Hi @maveň, thanks for your reply.. Can I create custom size image with that tools?